How can I add package on latex installation using package-set=basic automatic without using miktex console?
I am installing latex on different pc using Command-line installer standalone.
Using local-package-repository. But I don't find and option to select four extra package to install after install package-set basic.
The packages are: pdfpages, eso-pic, geometry, pdflscape
I don't want install package-set complete or install using GUI.
Someone can help me?

Welcome. The question is a bit unclear. Can you please add some more details?

Depending on whether you want to install in user-mode or in admin-mode you can use, e.g.
mpm --install pdfpages

resp.
mpm --admin --install pdfpages

on the command line to install, e.g., pdfpages after MiKTeX basic has been installed.
If you haven't already setup the local repository as default, you can add option --repository=LOCATION to specify it. Replace LOCATION either by a full qualified path to a local repository directory or an URL.
See the MiKTeX user manual for more information.
Note: You need the MiKTeX package name for this kind of installation not the LaTeX package name. Often the names are the same but not always. You can find the MiKTeX package name also in the CTAN catalogue entry of the LaTeX package. For example, for package typearea, the corresponding CTAN catalogue entry shows, that you would need to install MiKTeX package koma-script.
